# Unable to run Salesforce lightning readiness report

Tags: lightning

When I try to run the lightnig readiness report in the trailhead playground for Lightning Experience Rollout Specialist Challenge-1, I am getting the below error. I have tried running the report multiple times and I am getting the same error for last 3 days.

Offline for maintenance. The app in undergoing maintenance right now. Please check back later.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this issue as well. Looks like there are two issues possible:

- Your Files tab is full of .xls files and will not create any more when the readiness report runs.
- The Optimizer is actually down.

In this case it looks like we're all facing the latter.

Similar issue here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000MR4Y

Edit:
Seems to be a known issue right now. Looks like people are waiting on the Optimizer team to bring that service back up.

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?feedtype=RECENT&criteria=BESTANSWERS#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_SEARCH_RESULT&id=9063A000000pVgKQAU